# Remove item from firebase array with value using jquery

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove a value from firebase database with value using jquery.

[image]

I want to delete **235** value from the firebase.

I tried..

```
var dbRef = new Firebase("https://afgani-cinemas.firebaseio.com/");
var showId = getUrlParameter('showId');
var bookings = dbRef.child('bookings/'+showId);

 function removeFromFB(seatId){
    dbRef.orderByValue().equalTo().on('child_added', function(snapshot){
      snapshot.dbRef().remove();
    });
}

removeFromFB(235);
```

Any suggestions in my code. Its not working!!!

getting warning like this

firebase.js:40 FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": ".value" at / to your security rules for better performance

Comment: My first recommendation (without reading any further) is to upgrade to a more recent version of the Firebase SDK. The `new Firebase` syntax has been superseded over 1.5 years ago. For help in upgrading the code, see https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered

Comment: That warning should not prevent your code from working. It just warns you that the code is inefficient. See some of the previous developers who had this warning: https://www.google.com/search?q=FIREBASE+WARNING%3A+Using+an+unspecified+index

Comment: but the value is not remove from firebase ?

Comment: That could be, but it's unrelated to the warning message. Is you `child_added` callback being invoked?

Comment: No. There is no change happening in firebase after this execution.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. Is your function being called at all? So: if you put a `console.log("yay")` in there, does it print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code snippet

```
var bookings = firebase.child('root/321');
 function removeFromFB(valu){
    bookings.on('child_added', function(data) {
        if(data.val()==valu){
            bookings.child(data.key()).remove();
        }

});
}
removeFromFB(deleteValue);
```

in your case "deleteValue" will be **235**